# Помогите почему не выполняется запрос в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку: 
**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in s_bd.php on line **33**
 -  не могу понять причину. Вот код этого файла:

```
class BD{

public $res;
public $row;

private $host = "localhost";    
private $user_name;
private $user_password;
private $bd;
private $id;
private $link;
private $query;

public function __construct($id_gamer,$user_name, $user_password, $bd){
    $this->user_name = $user_name;
    $this->user_password =$user_password;
    $this->bd =$bd;
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->startConnect();
}

private function startConnect(){
    if(!is_string($this ->user_name)){
        $this ->user_name = strval($this ->user_name);
    }

    $this->link = new mysqli($host, $user_name, $user_password, $bd);
    if ($this->link->connect_errno) {
        echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $this->link->connect_errno . ") " . $this->link->connect_error;
    }else { 
        $this->query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM `platform` WHERE `id_platform`=? ");
        var_dump($this->query);//вот тут возвращает - bool(false)
        $this->query->bind_param('i',strval($this->id)); 
        $this->query->execute(); //выполняем запрос

        $res = $this->query->get_result(); 
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            print_r($row);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php) возвращает false в случае ошибки. Именно это у вас и происходит. Само выражение выглядит правильным, но в конструктор mysqli вы передаёте переменные, которые до этого не были инициализированы. Скорее всего, дело именно в этом.
В официальной документации рекомендую проверять наличие ошибки при помощи [$mysqli->connect_error](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.connect-error.php)

Как [пишут в комментариях](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.connect-errno.php) к документации свойства connect_errno, оно не возвращает ошибку, если передан пустой хост или пользователь (у вас именно так) на php 5.5.9 и выше (у вас, судя по всему, эта версия или новее).

Comment: Если обратите внимание, то в блоке IF я как раз использую это $this->link->connect_errno. И $link возвращается. Поломка начинается вот тут $this->query = $this->link->prepare....

Comment: Разумеется, я обратил на это внимание. Поэтому и указал, что в официальной документации для проверки на ошибку используется свойство connect_error, а не connect_errno.

Comment: Я не знаю, возможно, в php резолвятся параметры объекта без указания $this, для поддержки какой-то обратной совместимости, но, скорее всего, вам нужно передать в конструктор корректные значения через $this->host и т.д.

Comment: И в документации сказано, что "Если соединение установить не удалось, метод все равно вернет объект." (http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: Без разницы connect_errno возвращает код ошибки, а connect_error текст ошибки. Но эти обе функции срабатывают только при подключении. Что бы найти ошибку запроса нужно использовать оказывается <b>mysqli::$error, mysqli::$errno</b> соответственно. Они мне и помогли найти причину такого поведения.

Comment: Что это была за причина?

Comment: Не помогает ни connect_error, ни connect_errno при такой ошибки как у меня. Они просто не определяются. Ни разу не выдали ошибки эти 2 функции словно подключение проходило нормально. А на самом деле это было не так.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку мне всё же показали вместо:

```
$this->link = new mysqli($host, $user_name, $user_password, $bd);
```

нужно:

```
$this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user_name, $this->user_password, $this->bd)
```

Comment: Так ведь я об этом в своём ответе и комментариях и написал. И о том, почему у вас connect_errno не работало.

Comment: @АлексейУколов Как я понимаю мои значения были не доступны, поэтому использовались значения по умолчанию. Так как использую локальный сервер при разработке(как мы все), эти значения видимо до какого-то момента прокатывали...